# Saving vertex normals in obj file

Tags: c++, vertex, normals

I'm new on programming graphics and I have to display faces in 3D for a project at my university. For lightning and shading and stuff I need the vertex normals and for some reasons they are missing in several object files I'm using. 
I've been googling this topic for days so you guys are (almost) my last hope: 
Is there a tool where I basically just put my obj file in and it calculates the missing normals and saves them in the file?
I know I could calculate the normals myself but it would save a lot of time if I needn't.
Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: I think you provided very little information and you expect too much.. here on SO you ask question of type(almost always).. I have this code and this does not work.. or I get this kind of error.. this question will be probably closed as too broad - please provide some more info like what is the format of the object file - are they c++ object files (this sounds weird.. I have little knowledge on 3D graphics implementation), do you use some graphical engine? care to share some of your code..

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're already loading an obj file and parsing it you might as well calculate the normals at the same time. If there are no vertex normals, just do a little Cross(AB, BC).Normalize() and store that per triangle (or quad). If you want a normal per vertex you can average all the normals over a vertex, e.g. if a vertex is part of 5 triangles, add the 5 normals to that vertex then divide by 5 so you have a normal per vertex. Might take an extra intermediary data structure, but should be simple enough.

If you're allowed to use libraries, ASSIMP is the library I've used to parse a variety of file formats into a uniform format. They'll probably calculate the normals for you. But since this is for a university graphics class you probably should do the work yourself.